# RedGate Ants performance profiling to profile processes invoked from within running and attached executable

Tags: .net

There is a standalone executable which is in a server-client setup.I start a profiling session on this exe.From within this client, another .Net executable is started which is my target apllication for profiling.How can I attach to the second application.

Comment: Can you please be more specific - currently your question isn't clear.

Comment: When I start profiling the parent application ,am unable to profile a target child application.Even after enabling 'Profiling Child Process' radio button ,i ma unable to see profiling info of my target child application.